# printf doesn't behave as I imagine it ought to

Tags: c

If I run the code below it won't display the whole answer (`last printf("")` is the answer). I would like to know why it doesn't display the whole answer. Does anyone know this problem?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int M,T,P,K,H;
    printf("Teekonna pikkus:\n");
    scanf("%u", &P);
    printf("Tarbitud k\u00FCtuse kogus:\n");
    scanf("%u", &K);
    printf("K\u00FCtuse liitri hind:\n");
    scanf("%u", &H);
    T = K/(P/100);
    M = K*H;
    printf("Olete s\u00F5itnud %u", P," kilomeetrit ning kulutanud %u", K," liitrit kütust. Teie auto k\u00FCtusekulu oli %u", T," liitrit 100 kilomeetri kohta. S\u00F5idu maksumus oli %u", M," eurot.");
    while(1);
}
```

Comment: Why do you have a `while(1)` at the end of your program? First of all, lookup `printf` syntax. Then `printf` is probably not flushing the string to `stdout`, try adding a `\n` at the end of the format string, or add `fflush(stdout);` after the `printf` statement. Also, technically your program has undefined behavior because you have a infinite loop.

Comment: @Praetorian while(1) is possibly for not to lose the console window. a getch or scanf would be better of course.

Comment: @SedatKapanoglu You are right, it was written there for that :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The printf has the following syntax:

```
int printf ( const char * format, ... );
```

the first parameter is the format and all the others variables can substitute placeholders present in the format.

You should write:

```
printf("Olete s\u00F5itnud %u kilomeetrit ning kulutanud %u liitrit kütust. Teie auto k\u00FCtusekulu oli %u liitrit 100 kilomeetri kohta. S\u00F5idu maksumus oli %u eurot.", P, K, T, M);
```

Answer (score 2):

That isn't the way `printf` works. Put all the arguments after the format string.

```
printf("Olete s\u00F5itnud %u kilomeetrit ning kulutanud %u liitrit kütust. Teie auto k\u00FCtusekulu oli %u liitrit 100 kilomeetri kohta. S\u00F5idu maksumus oli %u" eurot.", P, K, T, M);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 problems in the code:

- `printf()` should be used as: `printf("P: %d - T: %d\n", P, T);`
- but there is also the possibility of a **division by zero**:

`T = K/(P/100);`

`P` is an `integer`, and if `P/100` becomes small enough, it will be rounded off to 0. Then `K/0` (zero) will create a problem.

So, those values should be checked before division. And it might be better to use (or convert to) `float` or `double` for some variables.

Comment: T = K/(P/100); was actually suggested by my teacher so it shouldn't make any problems, but thanks for the info :)

Comment: @MihkelKull - You can be sure it is a problem :) - You really should check those values, and maybe even use floats instead. (try using P<100 for example)

Answer (score 0):

[`printf()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) output is based on the first string parameter (formatting string), replacing the special `%` characters ("formatting specifier) in it with the additional parameters following the string.

So it displays only what you've asked to display, because you have only `%u` (unsigned int, which corresponds to `P`).  The remaining parameters are ignored, as no other formatting specifier can be found in the formatting string

You should concatenate all the formatting strings:

```
  printf (""Olete s\u00F5itnud %u  kilomeetrit ning kulutanud %u ...%u...%u...", P, K, T, M);
```

Comment: Firstly, I think `<iostream>` (not `<iostreams>`, by the way) is an absolutely ***terrible*** API, for many reasons. And secondly, the question is tagged with [tag:c] and not [tag:c++]. The fact that `<stdio.h>` (or `<cstdio>`) remains popular even in C++ says a lot, and it's *definitely* not legacy (even in C++, let alone in C!).

Comment: @TimČas sorry, but it was tagged c++ when I answered. About using printf vs. streams in C++: you may have your opinion on that.  It's just that printf() doesn't allow for object orientation as much as streams allow it. Now with a C tag, this is no longer an issue